# Nvidia 4060 TI 8GB slower than CPU in classification

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

I'm using this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

In tests, the cpu takes about 50seconds to run and GPU about 7-8 minutes. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

My cpu is a intel i5 10th generation with 96 ram. I would expect gpu to run at least 2x faster

I enabled mixed precision so that I make sure it is using tensorcores

from tensorflow.keras import mixed_precision
mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

What am I missing.... is rtx 4060 ti 8gb vram so slow when using classification algorithm?

I have about 1000 classes,but this is not relevant because cpu is alot faster ...

I'm using batches of 512, vram is at 6/8 and cpu most of the time is about 50%

I'm als doing BatchNormalization

```
model = Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  BatchNormalization(),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  BatchNormalization(),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  BatchNormalization(),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  BatchNormalization(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes, name="outputs")
])
```

ps: i'm new to ai

I tried using different batch size

I tried disabling the gpu and running just on cpu to make the test

I check out the ram, disk and cpu for bottleneck(none are 100%). When I run on cpu the usage is 100% and gpu 1% or less

These are the batch test I've done

```
Batch Time 
4 377s 
8  304s
16  317s 
32 335s
64 446s

And this is the model:

 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 sequential_1 (Sequential)   (None, 256, 256, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 rescaling_2 (Rescaling)     (None, 256, 256, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 16)      448       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 256, 256, 16)     64        
 ormalization)                                                   
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 128, 128, 16)     0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 32)      4640      
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 128, 128, 32)     128       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling  (None, 64, 64, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_2 (Batc  (None, 64, 64, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling  (None, 32, 32, 64)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_3 (Batc  (None, 32, 32, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 65536)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 128)               8388736   
                                                                 
 outputs (Dense)             (None, 863)               111327    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 8,524,351
Trainable params: 8,523,999
Non-trainable params: 352
_________________________________________________________________
```

And this is how I load the data:

```
folder = "some-folder"
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(

    folder,
 validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=1,
  image_size=image_size,
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    folder,
    validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=1,
  image_size=image_size,
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

And this is the autotune part

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1. / 255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
niter = iter(normalized_ds)
image_batch, labels_batch = next(niter)
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixel values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
```

Comment: What batch size are you using? GPU are not automatically faster, there are many similar questions here, and the answer is usually: model not big enough for a GPU, or other kind of bottleneck.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I added in description 4-64 , I also added the output of the model. So should I understand my model is too small? I'm using 256x256. So what is weird is that the best batch is 304s. When this happen GPU or CPU is not at max, memory is not at max. The HDD is not even at 10%, cuda mostly is close to 0.. I don't understand what am I missing. list_physical_devices confirms I have  a GPU. I can't believe is so slow and there is nothing I can do

Comment: That batch size is too small, try something like 256 or 512.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried and is even slower, that's what I don't understand. When I put a bigger batch it spills into system memory. I see that my SSD is about 24-50 % with speeds of no more than 100 mb/s. I ordered a new one with 730 mb/s to see if that's the bottleneck, Because I really can't understand why is so so so so so slow

Comment: What is your Tensorflow/CUDA/CuDNN version? You can check it in the terminal with `python3 -c "from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info;print(build_info.build_info)"`. What dataset (also how big is it) do you use and how do you load it? Normally your GPU should be way faster than CPU..

Comment: You can use the Nsight Systems profiler to analyze the GPU workload and GPU usage. That will help pinpoint potential inefficiencies in the GPU usage. To get started: https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems

Comment: OrderedDict([('cpu_compiler', 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe'), @mhenning ('cuda_compute_capabilities', ['sm_35', 'sm_50', 'sm_60', 'sm_70', 'sm_75', 'compute_80']), ('cuda_version', '64_112'), ('cudart_dll_name', 'cudart64_112.dll'), ('cudnn_dll_name', 'cudnn64_8.dll'), ('cudnn_version', '64_8'), ('is_cuda_build', True), ('is_rocm_build', False), ('is_tensorrt_build', False), ('msvcp_dll_names', 'msvcp140.dll,msvcp140_1.dll'), ('nvcuda_dll_name', 'nvcuda.dll')]). Right now CPU is almost the same as gpu

Comment: @ZoisTasoulas I'm not familiar with Nsight Systems. The dataset has about 1000 classes.I will update this post with how I load the data.

Comment: I'm using image size of 256x256 ... Maybe this is the problem? What is weird is the bigger the batch is the slower is... shouldn't be the other way around?

Comment: It should be faster, yes. If you start the training, what does Tensorflow print out? Something in the direction of missing libraries? Also, you should use `dtype='float32` in your last layer (see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision#building_the_model a few lines in). And du you use the `normalized_ds` for training or just for visualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTX 4060 SERIES is not CUDA toolkit compatible.

Comment: nice ... so I bought a tensorflow video card that is able to do nothing... expensive and useless NGREEDIA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).